# How to clear search field if clicked on route link again

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am very new to both laravel and Vue.js. And I came across a bug/inconvenience.
I appreciate your help.

*Problem:*

1. User clicks link called "Product" in the sidebar, Product.vue file loads the list of products in the content div of page.
2. There is a search bar that helps user to search specific product.
3. Now its showing list of product matching search string but still the url of page is same.
4. Now.... if user clicks back to original link. it does not reset the search field because even when doing search the URL doesn't change.

**Laravel navigation view file :: nav.master.blade**

```
<router-link to="/Product" class="nav-link">
<i class="fas fa-users nav-icon"></i>
<p>Products</p>
</router-link>
```

**Route / Parent component**

```
let routes = [  
  { path: '/product', component: require('./components/Product.vue').default },  
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes 
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data:{
      search: ''
    },
    methods:{
      searchit: _.debounce(() => {
        Fire.$emit('searching');
      }, 1000)
    }
});
```

**Product.vue**

```
export default
{
data(){
   return{
      products:{}
   }    
},
created() {
   this.loadProducts();

    Fire.$on('searching', () => {
       let query = this.$parent.search;
       axios.get('/api/findProduct?q=' + query )
           .then( ({data}) => {
               this.products= data;
            })
           .catch(()=>{

          });
       })
   }    
}
```

How can I reset the search field. When user click the navigation.

Thank you

Comment: please share the parent component

Comment: Sorry, have updated the code from parent component.

Comment: did you try `mounted(){this.search = '' ;}`

Comment: I tried it didn't work... as page url is same... its not reloading at all... so its not calling mounted() or created() when i click the link second time....if i right click and open link in new tab... its working as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested you use the pattern EventBus

See https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

**event-bus.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

**Laravel navigation view file :: nav.master.blade**

```
<router-link to="/Product" class="nav-link" v-on:click.native="reloadProducts()">
  <i class="fas fa-users nav-icon"></i>
  <p>Products</p>
</router-link>

<script>
  import { EventBus } from "../event-bus.js";      

  methods: {
     reloadProducts() {
       console.log("Event close");
       EventBus.$emit("loadProducts");
    }
  }
};


</script>
```

**Product.vue**

```
import { EventBus } from "../../event-bus.js"; //Import event Bus

export default
{
  data(){
    return{
       products:[] // Change by array
 }    
},
created() {
   this.loadProducts();

   //listen event loadProducts
    EventBus.$on("loadProducts", () => {
      this.loadProducts();
     });

   Fire.$on('searching', () => {
      let query = this.$parent.search;
   axios.get('/api/findProduct?q=' + query )
       .then( ({data}) => {
           this.products= data;
        })
       .catch(()=>{

      });
   })
  }    
}
```

Comment: please say me @thecosmicguys02 it was helpful for you. I can help you in something more

Comment: I implemented vuex in the project and it worked fine. Since your answer would also have worked I have marked it as correct answer. Thank you for taking you time to solve this.